# Trait and device type for "open" and "close" actions?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm looking to build a Smart Home device for Actions on Google. My device will have an "open" and "close" action. These aren't really "on" or "off" and the `OnOff` trait doesn't really apply. The `Toggles` trait is maybe more close. But I can't figure out how to trigger it.

I have been using the `Switch` device as it most closely resembles my actual device (a garage door). But which trait should I be using that would let me trigger with something like "Hey google, open the garage door"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [OpenClose trait](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/openclose) to do these types of actions as of March 2019.

---

*Answer before March 2019*

There's currently no trait for "Open" and "Close". Right now the best bet is to use the `OnOff` trait. You can use [Shortcuts](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7390802?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) so that something like "open my door" maps to "turn on the door".

Comment: Shortcuts might be the answer. Am I correct that shortcuts are only client side?

Comment: Yes, shortcuts are configured for each user. It's more of a workaround.

Comment: There is now an [OpenClose trait](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/openclose) that you can use.